# How to align divs side by side without overlapping?

Tags: html, css

How can i arrange the div's in such a way that box1 will appear to the left and box2 to the center and box3 to the right, without overlapping?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="box1"></div>
    <div id="box2"></div>
    <div id="box3"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I've added my answer, but next time do a quick search as this question has been asked thousands of times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY THIS SIMPLE SOLUTION - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/o6joswcx/5/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">box1</div>
<div class="box">box2</div>
<div class="box">box3</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box{background-color:#eee;width:100px;height:100px;float:left;}
```

Comment: When using a class you should keep the names the same as they are seen as repeated (Word check maybe). ID's should be used when wanting unique names

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.alignDiv div{
    float:left; width:200px; height:200px; padding:10px; margin:10px;
}
.left{
    border:2px solid #f00;
}
.center{
    border:2px solid #000;
}
.right{
    border:2px solid #bff;
}
</style>

<div class="alignDiv">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="center"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could decrease a lot of your code by using classes and id's correctly.

Answer (score 0):

When using a class, the name should be repeated, and ID's should be unique. Really easy to do something like this;

HTML

```
<div class="box">One</div>
<div class="box">Two</div>
<div class="box">Three</div>
```

CSS

```
.box
{
    float:left;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    margin:10px;
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
}
```

Also, when thinkng about ID's and classes within `div`, here is a good thing to remember;

- ID's should be unique and used for the overall structure of the page.
- Classes should be used when you want to recreate similar content, like aligned content boxes.

Hope this helps